# Does the link gun repair nodes more quickly when amped?

Tags: unreal-tournament-3

I was playing a Warfare map recently and I picked up a damage amp as I headed toward a skirmish for the prime node, which my team was controlling. My team took out the attackers just before I arrived, so I decided to pull out my trusty link gun and repair the node before leaving for other team's core.

The prime node *seemed* kind of like it was repaired more quickly because I was amped, but I wasn't paying very close attention because I've never really considered it before. I was the only person repairing the node at the time. Does the link gun repair nodes more quickly when under the effects of a damage amp, or was I just imagining it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, the damage amplifier does not increase healing performed by the link gun to power nodes or to players.** The damage amplifier or Double damage as it was known in previous Unreal Tournaments only increases damage. I wish I could find a more authoritative source, but according to [this post](http://www.ataricommunity.com/forums/showpost.php?p=4730677&postcount=73) and my own personal experience, the damage amplifier has no effect on healing produced by the link gun.

If you noticed an increased healing, it is possible that another player with a link gun was nearby, creating [a power grid](http://liandri.beyondunreal.com/Link_Gun#Unreal_Tournament_3) or that another player may have been healing the node from somewhere out of your sight. There is also the possibility of it relating to a given mod or server setting.

Comment: Well, I was hosting the server, so I know it wasn't mods. As I said, though, it could just have been a result of me not paying very close attention (it was also pretty late at night by this point).